# Export InDesign layers to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, adobe-indesign

I have created the design of a website in InDesign (big mistake, I know...). The developer wants to have my layers in a Photoshop format. I do not want to start everything from the beginning. What can I do?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: 1)Why would a developer want a `.psd` file and 2)why would you work more when you can output as HTML from InDesign?

Comment: Actually, InDesign is a fantastically useful tool for laying out web page designs. It's way underutilized by the design community, mostly because InDesign users, in general, think with print and ePub, but not so much with HTML for the web.

Answer (score 4):

um...  I would HOPE the developer is using it as a reference point and plans to code what you have designed.  I would request clarification on this and you could provide a `.pdf` file of the website as a reference.

If they are trying to slice the file for a website that is a bad idea..  You could always extract the site in an `.xml` file from InDesign or even do a couple of options such as:

The following would work if you're using Creative Cloud and have setup your document correct AND are using character and paragraph styles:

[image]

[image]

If you have built the paragraph styles correctly for the site you could even export out as an `.epub`, unpackage the `.epub` and pull out the `.css` and `.xhtml` files for the website.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found is to copy and paste from Indesign to PS (normally a whole layer at a time). This converts the layer to a smart vector object which can be edited from PS through Illustrator. If you are on Mac there is a very good script out there that automates this (I think it's called PageToPSLayersV3)
I normally have a layer for say Top Nav, Slider, Article 1, Article 2, Footer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AppleScript that will do just that. I can attest that it does a decent job. You can find the download and instructions at this [link](https://www.oss-usa.com/blog/exporting-indesign-photoshop).